# Update certain keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I would not know very well how to explain it, I have two dictionaries, I know how to put them together, here an example:

```
dict1 = {'machine': {'ip': '123', 'name': 'example', 'disks': {} }, 'machine2': {'ip': '1234', 'name': 'example2', 'disks': {} }}

dict2 = {'machine': {'disk1': {'name': 'exampledisk', 'capacity': '123'}}}
```

To put both dictionaries together I use this:

```
        for key, value in dict1.items():

            try:
                value.update(dict2[key])
            except KeyError:
                continue
```

But the result is something like this:

```
{'machine': {'ip': '123', 'name': 'example', 'disks': {}, 'disk1'{'name': 'exampledisk', 'capacity': '123'} }}
```

And I would like to put the data for those disks inside the "disk" key, to receive something like this:

```
dict = {'machine': {'ip': '123', 'name': 'example', 'disks': {'disk1':{'name': 'exampledisk', 'capacity': '123'}, 'disk2': .... etc} }}
```

Comment: dict2 seems an invalid dict.
you can check it from here http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the nested `disks` dictionary within the value:

```
for key, value in dict1.items():
    try:
        value['disks'].update(dict2[key])
    except KeyError:
        continue
```

Obviously this is a very specific update assuming that all entries in `dict2` are disks. A more generic way to update would require knowing which keys in `dict2` correspond with the nested dictionaries in `dict1`.